# Strategies for editing reactive functions in Shiny, 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' error

Tags: r, debugging, shiny, reactive

Goal: I am trying to create a shiny app that displays (1) the stressplot of a non-metric multidimensional scaling solution, (2) a ggplot of the point configuration, and (3) the results of clustering the point configuration by plotting the point configuration and superimposing chulls of the clustering.

Problem: The first two plots work without difficulty. Instead of a third plot, I get the error: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

1. I would appreciate any advice on how to resolve the specific problem, i.e. "error in array: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'"
2. I would also appreciate any general advice on how to debug shiny. My only strategy is to treat the code like it isn't reactive code, and I suspect that this strategy isn't terribly effective.

My attempt to solve: I've searched the error on rseek and stack overflow and reviewed the posts. In some of the cases with similar errors the problem was that necessary data wasn't being calculated. I went through the code, treated it as normal (non-reactive) code, and used fake data. When I did this I didn't have any problem, so I assume it is something about the reactivity? Question 2 about how to debug is a reaction to the fact that trying to debug like the code wasn't dynamic didn't identify the problem.

Reproducible Example: I put together a shiny app that has randomly generated data. Before doing the testing I updated R and all the packages I use.

```
# Packages and options
library(shiny)
library(vegan)
library(cluster)
library(tidyverse)
options(digits = 3)
# Create dissimilarity matrix
d <- rnorm(1000)
mat <- matrix(d, ncol = 10)
diss_m <- daisy(mat) %>% as.matrix()
# Function
find_chulls <- function(df, x, y) {
  ch <- chull(df[[x]], df[[y]])
  df[ch,] %>% as.data.frame()
  }
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Research"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('dim', 'Dimensions', 2, min = 2, max = 15)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3('Stressplot'),
      plotOutput('plot0'),
      h3('Non-Metric Multidimensional Scaling'),
      plotOutput('plot1'),
      h3('2d Density Plot'),
      plotOutput('plot2'),
      h3('Cluster Analysis'),
      plotOutput('plot3')
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  nmds <- reactive({
    metaMDS(diss_m,
            distance = "euclidean",
            k = input$dim,
            trymax = 200,
            autotransform = FALSE,
            noshare = FALSE,
            wascores = FALSE)
  })
  output$plot0 <- renderPlot({
    stressplot(nmds())
  })
  pts <- reactive({
    nmds()$points %>% as.data.frame()
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(pts(), aes(x = MDS1, y = MDS2)) +
      geom_point()
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(pts(), aes(x = MDS1, y = MDS2)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_density2d()
  })
  df_cl <- reactive({
    km <- kmeans(x = pts(), centers = input$clust)
    cl <- km$cluster
    data.frame(pts(), clust = cl)
  })
  df_ch <- reactive({
    df_ch_temp <- df_cl() %>% group_by(clust) %>% do(find_chulls(.,     1, 2))
    df_ch_temp %>% as.data.frame()
  })
```

## The plot below is the one that doesn't work

```
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df_ch(), aes(x = MDS1, y = MDS2, fill = as.factor(clust)))     + geom_polygon(alpha = 0.10)
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input$clust` is undefined in:

```
df_cl <- reactive({
  km <- kmeans(x = pts(), centers = input$clust)
  cl <- km$cluster
  data.frame(pts(), clust = cl)
})
```

You need to add an input binding for clust, e.g.:

```
 numericInput('clust', 'Clusters', 2, min = 2, max = 15)
```

As for debugging: I added `browser()` at the top in `df_cl`, then execution stops and you can inspect variables and run code in the terminal (e.g. in Rstudio). When I ran `km <- kmeans(x = pts(), centers = input$clust)` I got the error you described and could then see that input contains no clust element.

Comment: Thank you. The advice of using browser() for debugging is extremely helpful.